# How do I set a cpu limit for an esxi vm?

Tags: virtual-machine, limit, cpu, esxi, hypervisor

I have an ESXi 5.5 server running one virtual machine which is given one socket with two cores. What I want to do is to limit these cores to 1500 MHz each to simulate software behaviour on slow machines. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

To improve `CPU` power efficiency, `ESX/ESXi` can take advantage of performance states (also known as `P-states`)
to dynamically adjust `CPU` frequency to match the demand of running virtual machines. When a `CPU` runs at
lower frequency, it can also run at lower voltage, which saves power. This type of power management is
typically called `Dynamic Voltage and Frequency Scaling (DVFS)`. ESX/ESXi attempts to adjust `CPU` frequencies
so that virtual machine performance is not affected.

When a `CPU` is idle, ESX/ESXi can take advantage of power states (also known as `C-states`) and put the `CPU`
in a deep sleep state. As a result, the `CPU` consumes as little power as possible and can quickly resume from
sleep when necessary.

There are power management policies which you have to select for proper CPU utilization. You select a policy for a host using the vSphere
 Client. If you do not select a policy, ESX/ESXi uses High Performance by default.

[image]

**Prerequisites**

ESX/ESXi supports the Enhanced Intel SpeedStep and Enhanced AMD PowerNow! CPU power management
technologies. For the VMkernel to take advantage of the power management capabilities provided by these
technologies, you must enable power management, sometimes called Demand-Based Switching (DBS), in the
BIOS.

**Procedure**

1. In the vSphere Client inventory panel, select a host and click the `Configuration` tab.
2. Under `Hardware`, select `Power Management` and select `Properties`.
3. Select a `power management policy` for the host and click `OK`.
   The policy selection is saved in the host configuration and can be used again at boot time. You can change
   it at any time, and it does not require a server reboot.